# calculating mean squared error for the Mean.

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

**Exam Question**
There are two independent random variables $X_{1}$ $\&$ $X_{2}$ that are having normal distribution with mean $\mu$. Further Var$(X_{1})=1$ and Var$(X_{2})=2$.an **unbiased** estimator for the real mean $\mu$ is given as :

$T=\alpha X_{1}+(1-\alpha) X_{2}$ .

We must yet to chose $\alpha \in [0,1]$ . For what value of $\alpha$ is the  **MSE**(Mean Squared Error ) of estimator $T$ for $\mu$ smallest?

**Answer given to the Question**

> Because T is unbiased it holds that MSE$(T;\mu)=Var(T)$ and with the fact that variables are independent it follows Var$(T)= \alpha^2 +2(1-\alpha)=3\alpha^2 - 4\alpha+2$. 
>   this is minimal for **$\alpha=2/3$**.

**My Question**
how does $\alpha$ ended up being $2/3$? what should I consider to calculate $\alpha$ to minimize MSE of an estimator?

Answer (score 2):

$(3\alpha^2-4\alpha+2)'=0\iff \alpha=2/3$.

Comment: could you elaborate on why have you differentiated it? how that makes MSE minimum?

Comment: Of course. The variance of $T$ depends on $\alpha$, namely $3\alpha^2-4\alpha+2$.  Now find the absolute minimum of that expression by known methods of calculus.